# Find the coordinates of the points where the two circles intersect.

Tags: circles

The two circles are:

$1$) $$(x-2)^2 + (y+1)^2 = 25$$

$2$) $$(y-2)^2 + (x+1)^2 = 25$$

Comment: Set $(1) = (2)$. You will get a relation between $x$ and $y$. Substitute in any equation to get the point(s) of intersection.

Comment: Or you could just graph the circles and check.

Comment: @Antonios-AlexandrosRobotis We can apply a trick by flipping the role of the axes but the mentioned cannot.

Comment: Perhaps I've misunderstood your comment, but the answer I linked should solve this question in generality: regardless of tricks or not. In either case, I do believe it answers this question.

Answer (score 2):

$(1)$ and $(2)$ are symmetric for $x=y$. The two points you are looking for are the intersenction between $(1)$ and $y=x$.

Therefore, the intersections are $(\frac{1 \pm \sqrt{41}}{2},\frac{1 \pm \sqrt{41}}{2})$.